# ADO.Net - Performance difference between Execute Reader and Execute Scalar

Tags: ado.net, executescalar, executereader

I know the purpose of Execute Reader and Execute Scalar. But Execute Reader can serve the purpose of Execute Scalar. So why to use Execute Scalar? Is there any performance difference between them?
Which is faster?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Difference depends on the `IDbCommand` implementation; often performance is the same when `ExecuteScalar` internally executes the same code as `ExecuteReader`: good example is [SqlCommand](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlCommand.cs): both methods call internal `RunExecuteReader` method, so there are no any difference in performance.

Many popular `IDbCommand` implementations work in the same manner as SqlClient (MySqlConnector, NpgSql, Microsoft.Data.Sqlite), but potentially it is possible to have ADO.NET connector that offers better performance for `ExecuteScalar`. 
In short, if you call concrete class (say, SqlCommand) you can use either ExecuteReader or ExecuteScalar. If you use IDbCommand interface (say, in reusable library) and know nothing about the implementation usage of ExecuteScalar may give some performance benefits when used with connector that has specially optimized implementation.